# How to mod_rewrite a URL but ignore directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

IN SHORT:
How to ignore all directories whe doing a mod_rewrite?

OLD site:
http://www.domain.com/shop/dir1/dir2/dir2/page.html

NEW site
I only want to get "page.html" and redirect him to /page.html

---

LONGER VERSION
Tried and tried, but failed. Hope anyone as an idea:

We have an old site that has everything behind /shop/ and that can contain directories followed by a filename, like page.html

My thing is, the directories are not important... It's all about that last page.

How can I ignore everything between /shop/......filename.html ?

So:
OLD site:
http://www.domain.com/shop/dir1/dir2/dir2/page.html

NEW site
I only want to get "page.html" and redirect him to /page.html

This must be easy, but I just don't know!

Thanks in advance